# Intercept alien attack

Tags: cipher

NASA has intercepted an alien transmission.
The aliens are going to attack the earth!!
However, no one has managed to decipher the last part of the message containing the first city in the world that will be attacked. 
Here is the last part of the alien transmission:

[image]

Can you save the world?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Okay I think I got it, but I might be a little off:

> They will attack Turin (Torino), Italy

Explanation:

> Each set of 7 grey and green columns corresponds to a binary number: In the first column, reading down, we get 100011, 1000011, 0000000, etc. These correspond to ASCII codes for capital letters, starting with A at 65/1000001. So the rows will give us C, CA, , CB, DA, CBA, CBA, C, then CBA, CA, A, A, CA, B, CBA.  These can be used as a binary encoding where A=1, B=2, C=4, and D=8. If we add up each row's letters with these values, we get 45069774 and 7511527. Then, since you have geocaching as one of the tags, these are probably latitude longitude coordinates (with decimal points missing), we can guess they're 45.069774N, 7.511527E, which puts us in Turin. I figured this might be a more pressing situation for you, since you have an Italian name, so that's why you were so anxious for us to figure it out. :)

Comment: Makes sense since OP used a similar encoding on his other puzzle.